# how can i merge two AbRecordRef togethers OR how to add ABRecordRef as a link to another ABRecordref?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, addressbook

i need to merge two person in the same address book
OR Add ABRecordRef as a link to another ABRecordref like adding first name

```
ABRecordSetValue(myRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Name", NULL);
```

So any duplication in Address Book will be disappear

Comment: wow, really you had no answers at all? Voting this question up. If you solved it yourself then please post an answer.